# Session sharing on WildFly is not working

Tags: java, session, jboss, wildfly

I just migrated from JBoss EAP to WildFly and I am facing some issues with session sharing.

Previously in JBoss EAP, in my `web.xml` I added the below configuration:

```
<session-config>
    <cookie-config>
        <path>/</path>
    </cookie-config>
</session-config>
```

And both the applications were generating the same session id.

But in WildFly the problem is, application 1 will write session as for example `123` in the path `/`, and if I open application 2 it will override the session as say `456`. Now if I refresh application 1 it will again override the session and the process keeps on repeating.

How can I successfully share sessions in WildFly?

Answer (score 1):

add jboss-all.xml

```
<jboss umlns="urn:jboss:1.0">
    <shared-session-config xmlns="urn:jboss:shared-session-config:1.0">
        <session-config>
            <cookie-config>
                <path>/</path>
            </cookie-config>
        </session-config>
    </shared-session-config>
</jboss>
```

Read this quide

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Web+(Undertow)+Reference+Guide